# Why does $\frac d{dx} \sqrt{1 - \cos^2(x)} = \cos(x)$ when $\sqrt{1 - \cos^2(x)} = |\sin(x)|$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Why does $\frac d{dx} \sqrt{1 - \cos^2(x)} = \cos(x)$ when $\sqrt{1 - \cos^2(x)} = |\sin(x)|$? I mean it's not equal to $\sin(x)$? Is this the right way to take the derivative?

Comment: Why is the first equality true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,$$\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(1-\cos^2x)=$$$$=\frac{\cos x \sin x}{|\sin x|}=\frac{\sin (2x)}{2|\sin x|}, \ \ (x \neq k\pi, k\in \mathbb{Z})$$
where the RHS is equal to $\frac{d}{dx}|\sin x|$ according to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3753083/752069).
Hence,
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}=\frac{d}{dx}|\sin x|$$
but **not**
$$\frac d{dx} \sqrt{1 - \cos^2(x)} \color{red}{\overset ?=} \frac{d}{dx}\sin x = \cos(x)$$
as you claim.

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x}=\frac{\cos x \sin x}{|\sin x|}$$ — Could you please include steps which prove this?

Comment: @Cognoscenti it follows from the chain rule. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

$$|\sin x|'=(\text{sgn}(\sin x)\sin x)'=\text{sgn}'(\sin x)\sin x+\text{sgn}(\sin x)\cos x$$ and

$$\text{sgn}'$$ does not exist where $\sin x=0$ and is zero elsewhere.

[image]